# Чтение xml c BOM через lxml

Tags: python, xml

Нужно разобрать xml, который лежит по ссылке. Хочу это делать через библиотеку lxml. Проблема в том, что файл в кодировке с BOM и парсер выдает ошибку.

```py
from lxml import etree

xml_url = 'http://my-url.ru/my_xml.xml'
xml = requests.get(xml_url).text

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

Ошибка такая:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

Что с этим делать? Как лучше удалить эти начальные байты BOM?

Comment: `text.lstrip('\ufeff')` ?

Comment: Ну или в самом requests для объекта ответа прописать кодировку `utf-8-sig` (если используется именно UTF-8 с BOM)

Comment: Провел эксперимент (WIndows, python 3.7). 'etree.fromstring(xml)'  успешно прочитало  байты с ВОМ, как UTF-8, так и UTF-16. Посмотрите внимательнее (напечатайте), что там в начале байтовой строки лежит. А, кстати, может не requests.get(xml_url).text, а requests.get(xml_url).content ?

Comment: @AlexTitov а у автора не байтовая строка

Comment: @andreymal да, конечно, я обычно использую `content` и подумал про байты. Думаю использование `content`, вместо `text` поможет.

Comment: Ошибка выглядит так, будто контент малформнутый, @AlexTitov прав, без примера контента трудно сказать. Может, BOM дважды стоит в начале, а может, сам контент содержит невалидный XML.